# Atomicity vs Conditional - synchronization mechanism

Tags: c, concurrency, synchronization, semaphore

> Two synchronization mechanism to manage Concurrency:
>
> 1) *Atomicity*: Ensure no other thread change data, while one thread is running
>
> 2) *Conditional synchronization*: Ensure code in different threads runs in the correct **order**.

---

As per my understanding, Using lock, `acquire()` and `release()` lock mechanism ensure synchronization, in atomic approach, which is first synchronization mechanism(above). Locks **cannot** get implemented using *conditional synchronization* approach

Can semaphore be implemented using only *atomic* synchronization approach?

or

Can semaphore be implemented using only *conditional synchronization* approach?

or

Can semaphore be implemented using both approaches?

*Note: Monitors can be implemented using both atomic & conditional synchronization approach*

Comment: Its been a while and I am not certain but I think its both. I can't think of something that is only Conditional sync. But it's been a while since I had the topic

Comment: A semaphore does much, *much* more than an atomic variable.  Comparing them isn't very meaningful.  A semaphore does something useful when the underlying variable could not be updated.  It then works with the operating system to ensure that the thread gets suspended and re-activated again when the semaphore could be acquired.  Do avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @HansPassant I think, Semaphore place ordering on scheduling of threads. So, Cant I say this as *conditional synchronization* mechanism(ordering)?